# VLOOKUP_ADD_Array Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to parse an excel document.

It works fine until I reach a cell whom has a VLOOKUP_ADD_ARRAY.

What my code does is:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(httpOrder.getFile());
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("MySheet");

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

   Row row = rowIterator.next();

   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

   while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

      Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

      switch (cell.getCellType()) {

      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        CellValue value = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateFormulaCell(cell)
        break;
      }

   }

}
```

I'm getting the following error: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Name 'VLOOKUP_ADD_ARRAY' is completely unknown in the current workbook

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: A quick Google doesn't find any references to that as a built-in Excel function - what is it supposed to do, and where does the implementation of it come from?

Answer (score 1):

I assume VLOOKUP_ADD_ARRAY is a user defined function. It would help if you could post what is in the cell the error occurs for.

If it is indeed a user defined function, you have to reimplement it yourself. You can check [this page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) for an example how to reimplement a user defined function.